# Dynamic filtering that allow selection of row in a table without reloading page using wpdatatable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, wordpress

First of all, sorry for my english. I will explain more in detail of what I want to achieve, i'm using wpdatatable to generate my data from the database on my wordpress website. So far so good, I have my data showing. I use the filtering option of the plugin which is what I needed. You will find in the image below how it appear on the front end.

[Fliter option from wpdatatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUthg.png)

So I have different tables, like 4 or 5 with all having the same column with is **Centrale** present in different toggle option in images below.

[Toggle option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYvt6.png) 
[Table exemple inside toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a749n.png)

As you can see there the **Centrale** in the table, all my database that will be present in there will have it in common.

Here my question and hope I can find a solution. When I filtered by searching for terms in the **Fliter option from wpdatatable** it working and this will be my main table that will be use to show result on the different tables present in the toggle option. When I'm done with my filtering, I select on **Choix** which will be like a selection, it affect also the other tables which has the same **Centrale** in common without reloading the page. And it only pull data from the **Centrale** I select.

I really don't know how to do it. Here are the query use to pull the data:

*Main table* **updated**

```
SELECT 'CHOIX' AS Choix, Centrale, Revendeur, Region, Departement FROM _centrales
```

*Other tables*

```
Select Raison_sociale, Rue, CP, Localite, Telephone, Centrale From _revendeurs

SELECT Date_debut, Date_fin, Nom_centrale, Action, Designation, Mini_Cde, Reference, Tarif_net_action, PVC, Commentaires FROM _operations
```

Thank you all for your help in advance. I hope there's enough information.

Comment: Side note: `concat('CHOIX') AS Choix` be be better written as `'CHOIX' AS Choix` both statements do to same things.. see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6cjaheWzU9Wfg41wA5CvF9/0

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you, just correct it on my query, i'm still searching answer for my main question.